# Data not printing in .csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to learn web scraping in Python and trying to get the list of comapnies that are attending a particular tradeshow.

I want to print the list of those companies in a csv file but the csv appears in Jupyter notebook and have line breaks (\n \t \t)

Here is my code:

```
for item in items:
    exhibitors = item.find('h3', {'class': 'elementor-portfolio-item__title'}).text
    print(exhibitors)

for item in items:
    dictionary = {
    'exhibitors': item.find('h3', {'class': 'elementor-portfolio-item__title'}).text
    }
    company_list.append(dictionary)
print(company_list)

df = pd.DataFrame(company_list)
df.to_csv('company_list.csv', index=False)
print('done')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHlk1.png)

This is the output I am getting and when I download the csv file from Jupyter, it does not show any data.

Comment: What are we looking at in the image? Only the output of the first print? As a direction to offer towards cleaning this up, you probably need to look into using the string method `.strip()` often when parsing text. You title is a symptom of not debugging upstream steps first.

Comment: Hi Wayne, the image is the output of the .csv code. It does not open a csv file instead, it makes another Jupyter Notebook with the output. When I download the file, there is no data in the downloaded file. Can you tell me where I can write .strip()  ?

Comment: You aren't providing anything complete here to be much use. As I said, the CSV file contents are downstream of your probable issue. If you post code, show the output, or some examples of the result of that **always as text pasted in**. The use of `.strip()` string method was a stab at a possible solution for your whitespace presence in the CSV. I cannot offer specifics for the reason covered in my first statement in this comment. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The image is not the output of csv. It is obviously the output of you `print(exhibitors)`